# how to use while loop in pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

I am trying to add the user inputs using a while loop and If statements. I am having trouble figuring out how to add all the `userNumbers` to each other. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    //variables
Declare Integer userIn = 0
Declare Integer total = 0




//read numbers and calculate
While decision == decY
    Display “Please enter your numbers: ”
    Input decision
    If UserIn > 0 
       Display userNumbers
       Set total = userIn + 1
       Display “Would you like to enter another number Y/N?”
       Input decision
       If decision == decN
          Display “Done reading numbers, your total is ”, total
       End If
    End If
End While
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Decide on a separator for the input, unless they're only allowed to enter a single number at a time in which case you can skip to 3.
2. Use string splitting to cut the input up and then loop through that list with for, while, do, until, or etc.
3. Create a sum total variable and add each input value to it, e.g. `sum = sum + split_input[index]`, or if it will only allow a single input at a time `sum = sum + input`.

---

Some Notes:

Adding a value to a variable can be shortened to `variable += value` to add a value to an existing variable and assign the result to the variable, but not all languages support this syntax.

Not all programming languages start at 0 for list indices, so be sure to change the starting index accordingly.